# Vector is not updated, after performing a class method (c++)

Tags: c++

I have the following class:

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <set>
#include <utility>

using namespace std;

class HotelManagement {

public:

  HotelManagement() : hotel_clients(),hotel_rooms(), hotel_time(){}

  void Book (int time, string hotel_name, int client_id, int room_count){
    hotel_clients[hotel_name].push_back(client_id);
    hotel_rooms[hotel_name].push_back(room_count);

    hotel_time[hotel_name][time] = hotel_time[hotel_name].size();
    current_time = time;
  }

  int Clients(string hotel_name){
    map<int,int> times = hotel_time[hotel_name];
    if(times.empty()){
      return 0;
    }

    int time_start = current_time - 86400;
    int time_end = current_time;

    auto start_it = times.upper_bound(time_start);
    auto end_it = times.lower_bound(time_end);

    int number_clients = end_it->second - start_it->second;

    for (auto it = times.begin(); it != times.end(); ++it) {
        std::cout << "Key: " << it->first << ", Value: " << it->second << std::endl;
    }

    return number_clients;
  }


  int Rooms(string hotel_name){
    map<int,int> times = hotel_time[hotel_name];
    vector<int> rooms = hotel_rooms[hotel_name];

    if(times.empty()){
      return 0;
    }

    int time_start = current_time - 86400;
    int time_end = current_time;

    auto start_it = times.upper_bound(time_start);
    int start_index = start_it->second;

    auto end_it = times.lower_bound(time_end);
    int end_index = end_it->second;

    int total_room = 0;
    for(int i = start_index; i < end_index; ++i){
      total_room += rooms[i];
    }
    return total_room;
  }


  int check_hotel_size(string hotel_name){
    return hotel_clients[hotel_name].size();
  }


private:
  map<string,vector<int>> hotel_clients;
  map<string,vector<int>> hotel_rooms;
  map<string,map<int,int>> hotel_time;

  int current_time = 0;

};
```

where:

- **BOOK time hotel_name client_id room_count** — Book by the client with ID client_id a certain number of rooms (room_count) at the hotel named hotel_name at the specified time (time). Time is measured in seconds from a certain moment.
- **CLIENTS hotel_name** — Display the count of different clients who have booked rooms at the hotel named hotel_name in the last 24 hours. More formally, the time range of interest is described as follows: let current_time be the time of the last BOOK event. In this query, consider all events with current_time - 86400 < time ⩽ current_time, where 86400 is the number of seconds in a day. Note that the last booking should be considered, and a booking exactly 24 hours prior to it should not be included.
- **ROOMS hotel_name** — Display the count of rooms booked in the last 24 hours at the hotel named hotel_name.

Basically in the **BOOK** function I update 3 maps:

```
  map<string,vector<int>> hotel_clients;
  map<string,vector<int>> hotel_rooms;
  map<string,map<int,int>> hotel_time;
```

When I checked a size of each of them directly in the book method - everything works as it should.

But when I use **CLIENTS** function, for example, all these maps are empty and I don't know why.

Here is a small example for reproduction:

```
int main() {

  ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
  cin.tie(nullptr);

  HotelManagement hotel;

  int query_count;
  cin >> query_count;

  for (int query_id = 0; query_id < query_count; ++query_id) {
    string query_type;
    cin >> query_type;

    if (query_type == "BOOK") {
      int time, client_id, room_count;
      string hotel_name;
      cin >> time >> hotel_name >> client_id >> room_count;
      hotel.Book(time, hotel_name, client_id, room_count);
    } else if (query_type == "CLIENTS") {
      string hotel_name;
      cout << hotel.Clients(hotel_name) << "\n";
    } else if (query_type == "ROOMS") {
      string hotel_name;
      cout << hotel.Rooms(hotel_name) << "\n";
    } else if (query_type == "CHECK") {
      string hotel_name;
      cout << hotel.check_hotel_size(hotel_name) << "\n";
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Input values:

```
4
BOOK 12 h1 1 2
BOOK 13 h1 2 3
BOOK 14 h1 3 4
CHECK h1 #result is 0 for every map (I was changing function for every map size output)
```

Comment: Please try to create a [mre] to show us. With emphasis not only on the reproducible part, but also the *minimal* part. Hard-code the functions calls needed to replicate the problem in your `main` function.

Comment: As a possible hint, you seem to be using a lot of *copying* of your containers. Use *references* instead.

Comment: This might help: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems).

Comment: Voting to close as typo. `CHECK` option doesn't read any arguments from `std::cin`, it always calls `check_hotel_size` with empty string as argument. But the other functions probably suffer from what Some Programmer Dude mentioned.

Comment: Thank you for your comments! Especially about reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to read the name of a hotel to query the size. Add code to read that.

```cpp
    } else if (query_type == "CHECK") {
      string hotel_name;
      cin >> hotel_name; // add this
      cout << hotel.check_hotel_size(hotel_name) << "\n";
    }
```

This fix should also be done for `"CLIENTS"` and `"ROOMS"`.

Comment: I was so blind! Thank you for the answer.